# How to get a reproducible result when using parallelization to do resampling with mlr3

Tags: r, promise, parallel-processing, mlr3

Recently I was learning about using mlr3 package with parallelization. As the introduction from mlr3 book (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/technical.html) and tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T43hO2o_nZw&t=1s), mlr3 uses the future backends for parallelization. I run a simple test with the following code:

```
# load the packages
library(future)
library(future.apply)
library(mlr3)

# set the task
task_train <- TaskClassif$new(id = "survey_train", backend = train, target = "r_yn", positive = "yes")

# set the learner
learner_ranger <- mlr_learners$get("classif.ranger")

# set the cv
cv_5 <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)

# run the resampling in parallelization
plan(multisession, workers = 5)
task_train_cv_5_par <- resample(task = task_train, learner = learner_ranger, resampling = cv_5)
plan(sequential)
task_train_cv_5_par$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))
```

The AUC changes every time, and I know that because I do not set the random seed for parallelization. But I have found many tutorials about future packages, the way to get a reproducible result with future is using **future_lapply** from future.apply package and set **future.seed = TRUE**. The other way is something like setting future backend for foreach loop using %dorng% or registerDoRNG().

My question is how can I get a reproducible resampling result in mlr3 **without using future_lapply or
foreach**? I guess there may be a simple way to get that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed your example to be reproducible to show that you just need to set a seed with `set.seed()`:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)

task_train <- tsk("sonar")
learner_ranger <- lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "prob")
cv_5 <- rsmp("cv", folds = 5)
plan(multisession, workers = 5)

# 1st resampling
set.seed(1)
task_train_cv_5_par <- resample(task = task_train, learner = learner_ranger, resampling = cv_5)
task_train_cv_5_par$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))

# 2nd resampling
set.seed(1)
task_train_cv_5_par <- resample(task = task_train, learner = learner_ranger, resampling = cv_5)
task_train_cv_5_par$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))

# 3rd resampling, now sequential
plan(sequential)
set.seed(1)
task_train_cv_5_par <- resample(task = task_train, learner = learner_ranger, resampling = cv_5)
task_train_cv_5_par$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))
```

You should get the same score for all three resamplings.

Comment: I have tried your method and it works fine, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a seed with a RNG kind that supports parallelization.

```r
set.seed(42, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
```

See `?RNGkind` for more information.

AFAIK for deterministic parallel results in R there is no other way than using this RNG kind. When running sequentially, you can just use the default RNG kind with `set.seed(42)`.

> My question is how can I get a reproducible resampling result in mlr3 without using future_lapply or foreach?

{mlr3} uses {future} for all kind of internal parallelization so there is no way around {future}. So yes, set `future.seed = TRUE` and you should be fine.

Comment: Some minor corrections for the latest CRAN version: 

(1) You don't need to select a different RNGkind, sticking to the default is fine. future automatically takes care about the rest.
(2) We set `future.seed` to `TRUE` internally.

Comment: I tried ```set.seed(42, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")``` and ```set.seed(42)```, and they get the same result. I used to learn that  it is not recommended to use ```set.seed()``` in using **parallel**  to do parallelization, but it seems to be simpler in the future backend than parallel.